# Learning going from version 1 to 2?

Tags: migration, d

I learned D version 1. Version 2 is recommended and someone mentioned there are new interesting language features. What is the best guide going from version 1 to 2. I rather not reread everything i know about D, just the new features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [feature list](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/features2.html) covers many of the difference at a high level.

Comment: I am still interested in other others

Answer (score 7):

D2 also introduced

- more [compile-time reflection](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/traits.html),
- [alias this](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html#AliasThis),
- [template alias parameters](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/template.html#TemplateAliasParameter),
- [const correctness](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/const3.html),
- globals being TLS vars and the [shared](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/migrate-to-shared.html) type,

Phobos has been turned upside down plus the concept of [ranges](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html) has been introduced.

Answer (score 5):

The concurrency chapter of tpdl is freely [available](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609144) and concerns an area where a lot has changed.